# Does PrimaryThenSecondary LocationMode check if RA-GRS for primary exists?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, retrypolicy

I am using LocationMode in order to Retry to download stream from the blob storage. In certain cases, RA-GRS for the account might not exist. Do I need to take care that LocationMode is used only when RA-GRS exists for a storage account?

Comment: I've removed the tags from your question title as per the following section of the [tagging help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging): _"Should I use tags in titles?"_, which states you should avoid formats such as _"[tag]: [question title]"_.